# How to calculate the time difference between column 2 and 4, but under certain circumstances between column 3 and 4

Tags: r, time

How is it possible to calculate the time difference for the following issue:

## Data

```
n1 <- as.factor(c('yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 
                    'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes'))

n2 <- as.POSIXct(c('2006-12-10 13:01:22', '2006-12-11 12:13:11', 
                   '2006-12-12 13:12:11', '2006-12-13 11:01:22', 
                   '2006-12-14 15:13:11', '2006-12-15 13:12:11',
                   '2006-12-16 16:13:12', '2006-12-17 14:12:12'))

n3 <- as.POSIXct(c('2006-12-10 16:00:22', '2006-12-11 13:12:11', 
                   '2006-12-12 15:11:11', '2006-12-13 14:01:10', 
                   '2006-12-14 17:13:05', '2006-12-15 16:12:01',
                   NA, '2006-12-17 16:12:03'))

n4 <- as.POSIXct(c('2006-12-10 16:01:22', '2006-12-11 13:13:11', 
                   '2006-12-12 15:12:11', NA,
                   '2006-12-13 14:01:22', '2006-12-15 17:13:11', 
                   '2006-12-15 16:12:11', '2006-12-17 16:12:12'))

date <- data.frame(n1,
                   n2,
                   n3,
                   n4)
```

If n1 is "yes" then the time difference should be calculated between n2 and n3, but if n1 is "no" then between n3 and n4? Both calculations should be insert into the same column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `ifelse` function:

```
date$newcol <- ifelse(date$n1 == "yes", 
                      difftime(date$n3, date$n2, units = "secs"), 
                      difftime(date$n4, date$n3, units = "secs"))
```

Here, using **`dplyr`** to pipe and `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
date %>%
    mutate(newcol = ifelse(n1 == "yes", 
                           difftime(n3, n2, units = "secs"), 
                           difftime(n4, n3, units = "secs")))
```

Comment: That works, but do you also know a solution based on piping?